My HP Laptop - Pavilion 15, Windows 11 Mic is not working
My HP Laptop - Pavilion 15, Windows 11 Mic is not working, Its not recording anything or not working on google meet or elsewhere.
Methods I have tried

Give Access of Microphone
Update Driver
Uninstall and restart
checking corrupt drivers and reinstall
Disable enhancement

Settings Image - 1
Settings Image - 2
Settings Image - 3
Settings Image - 4
Settings Image - 5
Settings Image - 6
